# .getElementById working but not .getElementById().value?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I'm trying to get data that a user enters in a form text box to be generated by javascript. The form code is: `form name="Guest Comment" method="get" onsubmit="return FormValidation()">

```
        <div style="margin-left:30%; margin-right:30%">
            <fieldset>
            <legend><b>New Comment</b></legend>
            <br><br>

            Name: &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160; <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>
            Comment: &#160;&#160; <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment" Style="height:200px;width:400px" ><br><br>


            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit Comment" onclick="Add()"/>
        </div>
    </form>`
```

When I use the function below, it works but it cut/pastes the text boxes. So the text box will be missing from where it was above the comment submit button, and now will be down below on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Add(){
            var newParagraph = document.createElement("P");
            var name = document.getElementById("name");
            newParagraph.appendChild(name);
            var comment = document.getElementById("comment");
            newParagraph.appendChild(comment);
            document.body.appendChild(newParagraph);
        }
        </script>
```

So I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Add(){
            var newParagraph = document.createElement("P");
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            newParagraph.appendChild(name);
            var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
            newParagraph.appendChild(comment);
            document.body.appendChild(newParagraph);
        }
        </script>
```

But it does nothing. When I click submit nothing happens.

It's been a long couple days, what am I missing?

I don't know Jquery yet and I don't have time to learn it right this instant.

Edit: For example if the user enters: Name: [Rachel] Comment: [we had the most wonderful time at your establishment] and clicks submit, then below appears **_______________________________________________________________** Rachel We had the most wonderful time at your establishment! **________________________________________________________________** (okay, i don't know why the comment is not showing what I'm typing the way I've typed it but the users name should be isolated, followed by a 
 then the users comment) –

Comment: You should only include what is necessary in your question. e.g., CSS, odd HTML structuring, etc. shouldn't be in there.

Comment: are you looking for the `clone` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
<br>
Comment: <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment">
<br>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit Comment" onclick="add()"/>
```

add():

```
function add(){
    var newParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
    newParagraph.innerHTML = name + "<br>" + comment;
    document.body.appendChild(newParagraph);
}
```

You need to set the innerHTML of the paragraph.

[Here is a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/T7dtD/)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Unfortunately when I comment out my function and paste yours in, nothing happens when I click the submit comment button.

Comment: Because I named the function `add()` rather than `Add()`. Did you change your HTML to reflect that?

Comment: So you changed `<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit Comment" onclick="Add()"/>` to `<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit Comment" onclick="add()"/>` and nothing happened? You tried adding an alert() and the function literally is not being called?

Comment: I just added a capital A to add. When that didn't work I tried replacing my HTML with yours (and changing it back from Add to add). Where should I put the alert(name);? I tried putting it after newParagraph.appendChild(name); and nothing alerts Edit: okay, when I put it above newParagraph.appendChild(name); it alerts with whatever text I put in the name box

Comment: OK, the HTML and the Javascript need to write add() in the same way. Either choose both caps or both no caps. You've looked at the JSFiddle and tried to implement it? Also there is no newParagraph.appendChild(name)... are you sure you replaced your function with mine?

Comment: whoa, okay. I don't know what happened there. Let me try again.

Comment: Okay thanks that works. I don't know how the version of your code that I copied got so mixed up. Did you edit it a few times? Either way, thank you very much Neel.

Answer (score 0):

First off, `parent.appendChild(node)` takes a DOM node as an argument.  If that DOM node is already in the document, it will be moved to the location specified.

Second off, `document.getElementById(id)` retrieves a DOM node. `node.value` gets the text from a form field.  You cannot use that text as an argument to `.appendChild()`.  If you want to insert a copy of that text somewhere in the DOM, then you would need to create a new DOM node, put the text that you obtained from node.value into that new DOM node and then `parent.appendChild(newNode)` that new DOM node.

If you can clarify exactly what you want the end result to look like (show what the HTML would look like after hitting the Add button), then we could offer an exact code solution for you.  As your question stands now, it is not clear what you want the end result to be.

As a simple example, here's some code that reads from an input field and inserts that text into the DOM every time you press a button:

```
<input id="newComment" type="text" /><br>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button><br><br>
<div id="comments"></div>

<script>
function add() {
    var newText = document.getElementById("newComment").value;
    if (newText) {
        var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
        paragraph.textContent = newText;
        document.getElementById("comments").appendChild(paragraph);
    }
}
</script>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/T7dtD/

Comment: For example if the user enters:

Name: [Rachel]
Comment: [we had the most wonderful time at your establishment] 

and clicks submit, then below appears

___________________________________________________________________

Rachel

We had the most wonderful time at your establishment!
____________________________________________________________________

(okay, i don't know why the comment is not showing what I'm typing the way I've typed it but the users name should be isolated, followed by a <br> then the users comment)

Comment: @user3593798 - please use the edit button on your original post and add the new description information to your original post where everyone will see it and have a better chance at understanding it.  You can also use multiple lines and formatting much better in your original post than you can in a comment.